# Symlink in init.d directory is replaced with regular file after reboot system

Tags: centos, services, init.d

I create symlink in `init.d` directory: 
`ln -s /myservice.jar /etc/init.d/myservice`.

After reboot system symlink is replaced with regular file.

`ls -l /etc/init.d/myservice` output before reboot:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Mar 31 12:34 /etc/init.d/myservice -> /myservice.jar
```

After reboot:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41912304 Mar 31 12:40 /etc/init.d/myservice.jar
```

Why is this happening?

**upd.** On the server is used ISPmanager, can this be a problem?

Comment: I can't answer that because I've not got experience with it, but if you want to stop it you  might want to make the file immutable. `chattr +i filename` will make a file unwritable even by root until `chattr -i` is used to remove the bit.

Comment: Which version of CentOS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

what happens, if you execute

```
$ java -jar /etc/init.d/myservice
```

Does it work as expected? And does it happen to replace `myservice` with `myservice.jar` at that very moment of running the `java -jar` command? If so, then we have a clue about the mysterious behaviour you described.

Jar files are designed to be portable, while symlinks surely are not, so I'd expect this behaviour to be a blunt result of some auto-correction on Java's side to eagerly satisfy its classpath needs.

Regards, Micha

Comment: Spring boot create executable `.jar` file that, when launched by symlink, starts as a service. Before reboot system everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

Will `service myservice start` start you application ? (`service myservice.jar start`)

more important, will `service myservice stop` stop you application ?

file in `/etc/init.d` are services files.

1. They are supposed to be called with `start|stop|status|restart` as only argument. (`|` stand for or)
2. They are supposed to be linked *from* `/etc/rcX.d` where X in run level (0 to 6).
3. furthemore, some indication tell when to start them (before or after filesystems are up ? before or after network is up ? database ? webserver ? ), so rcinit will parse them.

Comment: In a traditional init subsystem a file in init.d is the definitive one, and the rc.d S* and K* files are the symlinks. i still haven't got my head around the mess that systemd has made of that all. (Sometimes the shims work but other times they don't.)